# Beyond Calculus?? Integral Convergence using Measure Theory & Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, definite-integrals

$$
\mbox{Does}\quad
\int_{\pi}^{\infty}
{{\rm d}x \over x^{2}\sin^{2/3}\left(x\right)}\quad \mbox{diverge ?}
$$

Is this problem suitable for a calculus class ?. I'm not sure exactly how to solve but I think it requires measure theory. Can someone lead me in the right direction ?.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: 
$$
\int_\pi^\infty \frac{dx}{x^2(\sin^2 x)^{\frac{1}{3}}}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{1}{x^2(\sin^2 x)^{1/3}}\,dx
$$
$$
\asymp \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2}\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{1}{(\sin^2 x)^{1/3}}\,dx.
$$

Comment: What does the equality symbol mean? Does it mean approximation?  If so, how does one get rigorous with it?

Comment: @user710587: I have never seen it used before, but it is the called `\asymp` in $\LaTeX$, so it probably means something like "tends asymptotically". I usually see "$\sim$" used for that. However, "$\le$" should probably be used there. Then this hint and my hint should provide a complete answer.

Comment: @user710587 Maybe not common. An example: $f,g:(a,b)\to\mathbf{R}$. Then $f\asymp g$ means there exist $c_1,c_2>0$ (independently of $x$) such that $c_1 |g(x)|\le |f(x)|\le c_2 |g(x)|$. In our case independently of $k$. In fact, as robjohn says, $"\le$" is enough.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\sin(x)^{-2/3}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(x)^{-2/3}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&\le2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\frac2\pi x\right)^{-2/3}\,\mathrm{d}x\\[9pt]
&=3\pi
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:Try to bound the integral near each aymptote. For instance, $\sin x$ is almost the same as $\pi-x$ near $\pi$. But is it larger or smaller?

Comment: If the inequality goes the wrong way, you can bound it more carefully.